# How to trim a set of numbers from a string in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

How to trim set of numbers from a sting in Jenkins. This is what I am trying but some how there is one mistake not able to fix it.

```
def Build_Num = sh(script: "echo ${BUILD_PATH} | awk 'BEGIN {FS="_"};{print $NF}' | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'", returnStdout: true).trim()

BUILD_PATH=ABC/EFGH/ABCD_1.2.3456.78912/
```

Result should be like this: `1.2.3456.78912`

Directly in shell I am trying to achieve with below command but not able to do it in Jenkins:

```
echo ABC/EFGH/ABCD_1.2.3456.78912/ | awk 'BEGIN {FS="_"};{print $NF}' | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your `$` character for your `awk` argument, otherwise Groovy will perform [string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).

Of course, we do not want to escape the `$` for `${BUILD_PATH}`, because in that case we *do* want string interpolation, we just don't want string interpolation for `$NF`.

Try this:

```
def Build_Num = (sh script: """echo ${BUILD_PATH} | awk 'BEGIN {FS="_"};{print \$NF}' | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'""", returnStdout: true).trim()
```